# nextFocusDown on empty EditText

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, focus

I have two EditTexts and need to place focus on the second one, once the user pressed "next" on the softKeyboard.
Here is my layout :

```
                  <EditText
                              android:id="@+id/Nom"
                              android:singleLine="true"
                              android:nextFocusDown="@+id/Prenom" 
                              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                              android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                              android:text="Nom"
                              android:textSize="35dp"
                              android:textStyle="bold" />


                          <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/Prenom"
                            android:singleLine="true" 
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:enabled="false"
                            android:paddingLeft="5dp"          
                            android:textSize="25dp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />
```

As long the second one is empty, no cursor is placed in it and I got a "beginbatchedit on inactive inputconnection".

But, when I put a " " in its text, there is no problem. Any Ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can remove

```
android:nextFocusDown="@+id/Prenom"
```

remove

```
android:enabled="false"
```

from your first edit box and just specify the input type,
when there are two continuous text boxes you press next of soft keys it will take you to next text box by default 
more information
[softKeyboard](http://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/style.html)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is the enabled="false" on your second EditText, just remove it:

```
                      <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/Prenom"
                        android:singleLine="true" 
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingLeft="5dp"          
                        android:textSize="25dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Comment: I remove it programmatically. Pb solved see above. Tks a lot for help